# Rhino mocks assertwascalled with indexer and args

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I'm trying to assert the following was called

```
cacheManager.Site[typeName] = items.Where(x => !requestContext.DefaultSites.Contains(x.SiteId)).ToList();
```

and I can't work out the syntax for indexers with args, I have this

```
manager.Site.AssertWasCalled(x => x[TypeName] = Arg<IList<FcCacheObject>>.Matches(y => y.Count.Equals(1)));
```

but its asking for the indexer to use args as well, how do I do this?

Comment: Are you using a mock or a stub?  Showing the full signature of the method you're trying to test along with the test setup code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple :)

I assume your indexer parameter type is `string`. Then in assertion instead of

```
x[TypeName]
```

use

```
x[Arg<string>.Is.Equal(TypeName)]
```

As result your assert should look:

```
manager.Site.AssertWasCalled(x => x[Arg<string>.Is.Equal(TypeName)] = Arg<IList<FcCacheObject>>.Matches(y => y.Count.Equals(1)));
```